# Why does SocialMediaData return such a small FollowerNetwork?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, social-media

I have hooked up my Twitter account to Mathematica and I have 1468 followers

```
myfollowers = Length[SocialMediaData["Twitter", "Followers"]]

1468
```

I wondered what my follower network would look like but the returned graph was far too simple looking:

```
a = SocialMediaData["Twitter", "FollowerNetwork"]
```

[image]

The graph only has 32 vertices:

```
VertexCount[a]
```

Looking at the names of the Twitter users it has included, it seems that it has only considered the most recent people who have followed me.

So, how do I get Mathematica to consider all of my followers?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but could you check if you can access another account's public follower list if you authorize the app?

Comment: Yes I can.  Interestingly, this is limited too.  For example `hugelist = SocialMediaData[{"Twitter", "stephenfry"}, "Friends"]` returns a list that is only 5000 followers long.  However, Mr Stephen Fry has over 5,000,000 followers!  Limitations on the Twitter API perhaps?

Comment: I don't know if this is the answer or not but, when applying `SocialMediaData` to *Facebook*, a similar thing happens, i.e. the vertex count of my Friends Network is strictly smaller than my number of Friends. In that context, I believe the reason has to do with my friends privacy settings which doesn't necessarily allow me to friends' friends.

Comment: Sounds reasonable for Facebook. Not so for Twitter. Only a tiny fraction of my followers would have a locked account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To honor Twitter rate limits, "FollowerNetwork" property gives a subgraph of the follower network.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1

You can build the full follower network (at your own risk):

```
With[{followers = SocialMediaData["Twitter", "Followers"], 
mutual = Complement[Intersection[
                    SocialMediaData[{"Twitter", #1}, "Followers"], #2], {#1}] &}, 
Quiet[Graph[Flatten[Table[Thread[f -> mutual[f, followers]], {f, followers}]]]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Killed my kernel.  Perhaps I am asking for too much all in one go.  So, I wonder how best to build this up a piece at a time so that I don't hit the rate limit?  Would also be fun to watch the graph build up slowly.

Comment: @WalkingRandomly Maybe what hangs is the graphical output? 1468 is a a lot to plot. Can you try `g = ... ;` to suppress graphical output. And then see if you can work with properties like `EdgeList[g]//Length` - which i bet is a huge number. BTW - great blog you have - I enjoy reading it.